# Laravel - Route that may contain a pagination/query url at the end - Pagination url doesn't add to the query url, it replaces it

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

So I have a products page where you may browse all products or browse queried products if you choose to. However in both cases they must have pagination. Here is my route:

```
Route::get('/products/{gender}/{subcategory_name}', [
    'uses' => 'ProductsController@showProducts',
    'as' => 'products'
]);
```

For the pagination links I use `$model->links()` in my views. Both the pagination and query work. When you decide to query the items you must still paginate them. However when I click to go to the second page the pagination url deletes my query url. The result is loosing the queried products and getting to the second page but with **ALL** products, not the **Queried** ones. Here is an step by step walkthrough for clarification:

1. I am on this url: products/Men/T-shirt
2. I click on the second pagination link so I can get to this url: **"products/Men/T-shirt?page=2"** // This works
3. I decide to query the items. Here is the url afterwards: **"products/Men/T-shirt?color%5B%5D=1"** // This works. I query the products and get the correct pagination links.
4. Now here is the problem. When I click the second pagination link of the queried products the pagination url delets my query url and I go to this link "**products/Men/T-shirt?page=2**". Now I am on the second page of **ALL** not the queried products. I need to go to the second page of the **QUERIED** products.

Solutions and advice are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to set sortkey=color&page={{Input::get('page','')}} in the anchor tag

Comment: Input is deprecated in Laravel 5.2. Even though I could most likely use Request instead of Input, I couldn't understand what you meant. Could explain with more details? @PardeepPathania

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell Laravel to append your own query parameters to the `links()` method, for example:

```
{{ $model->appends(['color' => Request::input('color')])->links() }}
```

To have the query params dynamically you could use something like:

```
{{ $model->appends(Request::except('page'))->links() }}
```

Comment: Wow. I wouldn't have thought that I could just change one line of code and fix this. I started trying hack my way around it. However your solution worked like a charm. Thank you :)